# What is the difference between "go on" and "go for" vacation?

Tags: collocations

For example,
I will go Mexico for vacation next month.
Vs.
I will go on vacation to Mexico next month.
Is there any difference? If not, which one is more common In colloquial AmE?

Comment: If it were me, I'd say either: "I will go **on** vacation to Mexico next month," or, "I will go **to** Mexico for **a** vacation next month." (I'd include an article with the _for_ form.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To *go on* vacation is to take a vacation.

But in my AmE dialect questions like these:

**Where are you going *for* vacation?**
-- I'm going to summer camp.

**What are you doing *for* vacation?**
--I'm working as an intern in a biology lab.

would be used when the vacation is not at an arbitrary time during the year (as the person taking the vacation sees fit) but at a time that occurs regularly, such as "summer vacation" (the summer months when school is not in session) or "winter break" (the time between Fall and Spring sessions).

**What are you doing for winter break?**

means "What are you planning to do during winter break?"

In this pattern, *for* is complemented by a noun-phrase which refers to a time-span.

**What are you doing for the year?

What are you doing for the summer?**
**What are you doing for the Fourth of July?**
**What are you doing for the next hour?**
**What are you doing for the next fifteen minutes?**

Comment: Can I say "What are you going to do for this weekemd?" or "What will you do for this weekend?"?  What are the differences?

Comment: @Jokaec: "What are you doing for *the* weekend?" and "What are you doing *this* weekend?" are the most likely forms, although "...for this weekend" is not an impossibility.

Answer (score 0):

They mean almost the same.

I've searched the collocation on `vacation`. The [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vacation_1) says that `go on (a) vacation` is more common in colloquial, so does the [Excitingfinance](http://excitingfinance.com/blog50.html).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, "go on" vacation is more common. However, both will be understood:

"I will go to Mexico for vacation" means the same as "I will go on vacation to Mexico."

As a side note, it is even more common to say, "I'm going on vacation to Mexico next month," replacing "I will go" with "I'm going."